# a combination of permutations of elements in a java array

Tags: java

I made a code that should show the entire combination of permutations of elements in an array.

```
    package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     first(3);
    }

    static int factorial(int n) {
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
    }

   static void first(int n){
      int[] array = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
          array[i]=i+1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < factorial(n);i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(j==n-1){
                    continue;
                }
                int t = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = t;
            }
            for(int k =0;k<n;k++){
                System.out.print(array[k]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            }


        }
   }
```

What should it be:

123
213
231
132
312
321

But it turns out like this:

231
312
123
231
312
123

How can a permutation be done the way it should?

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you handle your set of elements to permute as a string, there are numerous examples over the internet, like:

```
 public class Permute {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123";
        permute(str);
    }
    public static void permute(String str) {
        permute("", str);
    }
    public static void permute(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                permute(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's step back and review your underlying idea: I assume that you always take a pair of neighboring values in the array and swap those. So for the first step, you are swapping the values of indices 0 and 1, for the second step, you are swapping 1 and 2 etc. If you reach the end of your array, you are going back to the start, thus swapping indices n-1 and 0, then 0 and 1 again and so on.

Taking these preliminary thoughts into account, I came up with the following approach within the method `permutation` that uses mainly a `while` loop to find all `factorial(n)` permutations:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permutation(3);
    }

    static int factorial(int n) {
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
    }

    static void print_permutation(int[] array) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(array[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void permutation(int n) {
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            array[i] = i+1;
        }
        print_permutation(array);
        int counter = factorial(n);
        int i = 0;
        int j = i+1;
        while (counter > 1) {
            int t = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = t;
            print_permutation(array);
            // Swap the next pair of neighbors.
            // If there is no next value, use the first value again.
            if (i+1 == n) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
            if (j+1 == n) {
                j = 0;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
            counter--; // Stop after factorial(n) permutations.
        }

    }

}
```

The first step is similar to your own idea, just creating an `array` from 1 to n and printing the "default" permutation.

I reused your `factorial` function to create a `counter` value, which tells me when to stop looking for new permutations (it is used as a break condition in the `while` loop). I also added a little helper function that does the printing (which is not necessary, but better for understanding the overall idea of the algorithm in the method `permutation`).

Within the `while` loop, I basically just do what I already described above, always swapping the neighboring pairs of values (or jumping back to the start of the array) until `counter` has been decreased to 1.

For `permutation(3)`, this program returns:

```
123
213
231
132
312
321
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't lead to correct results for e.g. `permutation(4)`, thus I think, the general idea is not correct here.